# Boolean formula

Tags: javascript, boolean

Given an arbitrary formula of 2-valued Boolean algrebra, for instance (1V0)∧1V~(0∧1). How can I get a result of this formula using JavaScript ? I mean, a teacher gives a formula and my programm should print the result 1 or 0.

Comment: This doesn't have to do specifically with javascript, I is the same as it would be in other languages too. Try replacing each logical operator with its equivalent in javascript. Also the 1 and 0 will probably be in the form of string so I would replace them with `true`, `false`.

Comment: I think what OP means is that the program should act as interpreter and take textual form of this formula, and return the answer. But that's just my guess.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the purpose of this exercise is to learn the basics of parsing and formal grammars. Here's some info to get you started.

First, you split the input into "tokens", or symbols (operators, values, parenthesis). This is called "lexing" and is rather trivial in your case, because your symbols are always one character.

Then, you build a parse tree, or "AST", from these tokens. Each node in the parse tree is an object `operator left right`, where `left` and `right` could be values or other node objects. For example,

```
a v b ^ c
```

yields the following parse tree

```
   operator = v
   left = a
   right = {
       operator = ^
       left = b
       right = c
   }
```

To build a parser, you need to define a set of formal rules, called a "grammar", for your expressions. An example grammar for booleans:

```
 <b-expression>::= <b-term> [OR <b-term>]*
 <b-term>      ::= <not-factor> [AND <not-factor>]*
 <not-factor>  ::= [NOT] <b-factor>
 <b-factor>    ::= <b-literal> | <b-variable> | (<b-expression>)
```

(https://compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/tutor6.txt)

Once the AST is built, you "evaluate" each tree node with a simple recursive algorithm:

```
evaluate(node)
   if node is a value (e.g. "1"), return this value
   otherwise, 
        L = evaluate(node.left)
        R = evaluate(node.right)
        V = apply node.operator to L and R
        return V
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could use logical operators, like

- [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_())
- [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_())
- [logical NOT `!`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT)

and replace the given boolean operators.

```js
 console.log((1 || 0) && 1 || !(0 && 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input is always trustworthy, one option would be to transform the expression into proper JS syntax and then use `eval`:

```js
const check = str => Boolean(eval(str
  .replace(/v/gi, '||')
  .replace(/∧/g, '&&')
  .replace(/~/g, '!')
));

console.log(check('(1V0)∧1V~(0∧1)'));
console.log(check('0∧0'));
console.log(check('1∧1'));
console.log(check('1∧0'));
console.log(check('1V0'));
console.log(check('0V0'));
```

Comment: well, I guess this is from the compilers class, and I don't think "use a compiler" is a right answer to the question "how to write a compiler". Like saying "get a taxi" to a driving school student. ;)